# Can I use firebase to store objects?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am a novice android programmer, and I am developing my first android application. I'm trying to figure out if firebase is suitable for my needs.
My app looks like this:

- users add the product to the database by filling in the product
  fields
- products are stored in the database as objects with simple fields (numbers and strings)
- users search for a product in the database to compare its fields according to different criteria
- users edit (update) product fields
- users have their own accounts

My priority is the ease of use.

My question is:

1. Is Firebase suitable for my needs or is there a more suitable solution?
2. Do I understand correctly that I am interested in the Cloud Storage product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> users add the product to the database by filling in the product fields

Yes, you can achieve this using either [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) or the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write). In both cases, you can add the data as a Map object or as a custom object of your choice.

> products are stored in the database as objects with simple fields (numbers and strings)

Yes, you can achieve that. Here are [Cloud Firestore supported data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), as well as [Firebase Realtime Database data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write).

> users search for a product in the database to compare its fields according to different criteria.

None of the above databases supports native indexing or search for text fields, so you can use third-party libraries like [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) or [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/).

> users edit (update) product fields.

These are basic CRUD operations that are supported by both databases.

> users have their own accounts

In this case, you should use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth), a service that works perfectly with both databases.

> Is firebase suitable for my needs or is there a more suitable solution.

As I see in your requirements, yes, it suits your needs.

> Do I understand correctly that I am interested in the Cloud Storage product?

For storing data (objects) you need to choose one of the above-mentioned databases, or why not even both, and for storing files, you should indeed use [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage).

Answer (score 0):

You could use firestore for this. Although full-text search won't work, you can use algoia/elastic to do full-text search.